# GLSL Geometry Shader problems

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I have been pulling my hair out for 2 days over this.

First.. the code.. All of it.

```
//Leaf Vertex Shader
#version 330 compatibility 

out vec4 VertexColor;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewMatrix *gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0].st = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
    gl_TexCoord[1].st  = gl_MultiTexCoord1.st;
    gl_TexCoord[2].st  = gl_MultiTexCoord2.st;
    gl_TexCoord[3].st  = gl_MultiTexCoord3.st;
    gl_TexCoord[4].st = gl_MultiTexCoord4.st; // this is out size in x.y
    VertexColor = gl_Color;
}
```

Geo shader

```
#version 330 compatibility 
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable         

//uniform float uNormalsLength;      
 out vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 color;
layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;
void main(void)
{
    vec4 vVertex = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    vec2 uvs[4];
    uvs[0] = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
    uvs[1] = gl_TexCoord[1].st;
    uvs[2] = gl_TexCoord[2].st;
    uvs[3] = gl_TexCoord[3].st;
    vec2 scale = gl_TexCoord[4].st;
    float vx[4];
    vx[0] = -1.0;
    vx[1] = -1.0;
    vx[2] = 1.0;
    vx[3] = 1.0;
    float vy[4];
    vy[0]= -1.0;
    vy[1]= 1.0;
    vy[2]= 1.0;
    vy[3]= -1.0;
    int indi[4];
    indi[0] =  0;
    indi[1] =  3;
    indi[2] =  1;
    indi[3] =  2;
    texCoord = uvs[0];
    vec4 oVertex = gl_PositionIn[0];
    color = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
        oVertex.xyz = vVertex.xyz;
        color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);
        oVertex.x += (vx[ indi[i] ] * scale.x);
        oVertex.y += (vx[ indi[i] ] * scale.y);
        texCoord.xy = uvs[ indi[i] ].xy;

        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * oVertex;
        EmitVertex();
    }


         EndPrimitive();
}
```

Frag shader

```
// leaf fragment shader
#version 330 compatibility 
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
in vec2 texCoord;
in vec4 color;
out vec4 FragColor;
void main (void)
{
    vec2 uv = texCoord.xy;
    uv.y *= -1.0;
    vec4 t = texture2D(colorMap,uv);
    FragColor = t;
    FragColor.rgb += color.rgb;
}
```

When I send this a point, I get nothing out but a point.
I have tried sending triangle_stips.. It makes no difference.

When I check the int32 returned gl_getuniformlocation for colorMap, its -1.

It is almost like this program does NOT running when I call gl_useprogram. It has not effect.. I can't even effect the color and.. getting back -1 for colorMap makes me think the fragment shader never gets any input.
I have tried hard coding a vertex in the vertex shader and it makes no difference.

I'm not sure about the transform but I can't test this as I cant see ANYTHING but a point. Like I said.. Its like its never being loaded. If I send the vertices as a triangle_strip, I see a triangle_strip on the screen.
Thanks for any one that takes the time to read this.

Sorry about all the code but maybe someone can spot something I'm missing.
Also.. There is a lot of deprecated things in there but it has never been a problem in my other shaders.

Comment: How exactly did you pass your `colorMap` to shader?

Comment: You did not check to see if your shaders compiled&linked. Because I see several compile errors in them. And... lots of general confusion (like your need to enable the Godawful `GL_EXT_geometry_shader4` extension on GLSL 3.30, which has core GS functionality).

Comment: Also... what exactly is this code *trying* to do?

Comment: I'm not so good at this shader business but I want to learn and get my code optimized. I agree.. there are better ways to do this but at this stage.. I just want to get it working and its being ignored when I call it.

Comment: I left the 'Godawful'.. It can be removed as you said. Yes.. It compiles all shaders and links the program with no errors.. I even check with glGetError at different locations to see if some odd things are happening. No errors.. what this is trying to do is bill-boarding a quad shape to render leafs on a tree. As far as how i pass the colormap, I use `Gl.glActiveTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE0) Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, Trees.flora(i).branch_textureID)`

Comment: I fixed a typo in the fragment.. Duh.. I was just using texCoord.rg to see if it was effecting anything and never changed it back to color. Some progress.. when I send a triangle strip, I get a Id back for colorMap now but nothing in the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I'll try to point out all of the wrong things you do. But since there's *so much* that's wrong with this code, I probably won't get them all.

```
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable
```

The interactions between core [Geometry Shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) in GL 3.2 and the EXT_geometry_shader4 functionality is not well-defined. Therefore, exactly what this line will do is unknown.

This line, and any code that relates to it, should be removed. For example, the input variable `gl_PositionIn` is defined by EXT_geometry_shader4, but not core GS. Oddly, you do use that value, but you immediately overwrite it in the first step of the loop, for some reason.

```
uvs[0] = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
uvs[1] = gl_TexCoord[1].st;
uvs[2] = gl_TexCoord[2].st;
uvs[3] = gl_TexCoord[3].st;
vec2 scale = gl_TexCoord[4].st;
```

No matter what shader stage you put it in, `gl_TexCoord` *always* refers to the *output* of that stage. *Never* the input. So you're copying the value of a shader stage output variable that you never write to.

The correct input variable name would be `gl_in[0].gl_TexCoord[x]`.

The easiest way to check to see if you're reading an input variable in a GS is this: do you have to prefix/suffix it with an array index? If you don't, then it's *not* an input variable. All Geometry Shader input variables are arrayed.

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * oVertex;
```

In your vertex shader, you transformed the output position by `gl_ModelViewMatrix`. Which transforms the positions from model space to camera/eye/view space (whatever you want to call it). So those positions are now camera-relative.

The `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` transforms positions from *model space* to projection space. If your positions are in camera space (which, as previously established, they are), then this transformation is nonsensical.

The correct matrix to use here would be `gl_ProjectionMatrix`, which transforms from camera space to projection space.

---

This is what functioning code would look like. Code that uses the OpenGL 3.3 core profile.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core 
in vec4 position;
in vec4 color;
in vec2 texCoords[4]; //Yes, that's perfectly legal.
in vec2 scaleFactor;

out VS
{
    out vec4 color;
    out vec2 texCoords[4]; //Yes, this is legal too.
    out vec2 scaleFactor;
} dest;

//The transformation from model space to camera space.
uniform mat4 modelToCamera;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = modelToCamera * position;
    dest.color = color;
    for(int i = 0; i < texCoord.length(); ++i)
        dest.texCoord[i] = texCoord[i];
    dest.scaleFactor = scaleFactor;
}
```

Geometry Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, points) out;

in VS
{
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texCoords[4]; //Still legal.
    vec2 scaleFactor;
} source[]; //One for each input vertex, but since we're using points, it's just one.

out FS
{
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texCoord;
} dest;

const vec2 offsets[4] = vec2[4](
    vec2(-1.0, -1.0),
    vec2(-1.0,  1.0),
    vec2( 1.0,  1.0),
    vec2( 1.0, -1.0));

//The transformation from camera to projection.
uniform mat4 ProjectionTM;

void main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < offsets.length(); ++i)
    {
        dest.color = source[0].color;
        dest.texCoord = source[0].texCoord[i];

        vec2 scale = offsets[i] * source[0].scaleFactor;
        vec4 pos = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
        pos.xy += scale;
        gl_Position = ProjectionTM * pos;
        EmitVertex();
    }

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core 
in FS
{
    vec4 color;
    vec2 texCoord;
};

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D colorMap;

void main (void)
{
    vec4 t = texture2D(colorMap, texCoord.xy * vec2(1.0, -1.0));
    FragColor = t;
    FragColor.rgb += color.rgb;
}
```

Comment: Very good answer and explanation of my screw ups.

Thank you!